# How to edit html block?

Tags: jeditable

I actually created a new inputtype to use TinyMCE, but I saw problem, to make thing simple, I tested with existing "textarea" input type, and found I cannot make it work neither.

so I could have html like below

```
<div class='editable'>
<p>this is a <b>test</b></p>
</div>
```

when I make it editable as textarea and then click to edit, I expect to see code like below in the textarea

```
<p>this is a <b>test</b></p>
```

instead I see string with all tag stripped, I was told to use loadurl to get the content from backend when it is editted, I did that, which works fine.

But now I have another problem, if I click to edit and then click cancel, the stripped text shows, not the string with tags,  any idea what is that?  what happens to jeditable reset? where it stores the original text when user click edit and then restore it after user click cancel?

Comment: you are dealing with injection handling.  If you want to render what the tags are, you will need to escape them or replace them with their text variants via their codes:   `&gt;` for example

Comment: but how do I get the content when user click cancel?